# Forcing DFS replication on Windows 2003 Web Edition SP2

Tags: windows-server-2003, dfs

I have a pair of web servers running Windows Server 2003 Web Edition SP2 (build 3790).
There servers are a on a Gigabit LAN and are on the same subnet.

I created a new link on the 1st server and added the second box as a target to the link.
I configured replication as ring.

The 2nd server gets some of the files on the scheduled replication but this varies wildly which makes me think it's not running fully. The folder on server 1 is 1.3GB.

Is there some way I can force repication (from a console?) and monitor the progress and see if/when/why it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about forcing replication but I do know that you can generate a report on your DFS host machine that will tell you of all the failures that it's having.  You can also look in event viewer as there's a special section for DFS related errors in there.

Comment: Do you have a link to instructions? Thanks

Comment: When I get into the office in a few hours I will post how to generate the report.